# Multi series JSON data for Google Charts

Tags: c#, json, google-visualization

I am trying to create a JSON feed to return to Google charts a multi line chart, with four series. I am struggling to form the correct JSON to return to the charts.

I am using a stored procedure that produces a long list of the data I require to show in the chart. I want to be able to take the long list of data and convert it into four separate data series and send back to the chart in JSON.

My Model:

```
public class FoodCountCompare
{
    [JsonProperty("Count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Day")]
    public string Day { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }       
}
```

My SPROC:

```
    SELECT COUNT(P) AS 'Count', DATENAME(DW, fldTimeStamp) AS 'Day', @P AS 'Type' FROM [dbname].[FoodTypes] WHERE Protein = 1 AND fldUserId = ''+ @UserId+'' GROUP BY DATENAME(DW, fldTimeStamp)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(H) AS 'Count', DATENAME(DW, fldTimeStamp) AS 'Day', @H AS 'Type' FROM [dbname].[FoodTypes]WHERE HEC = 1 AND fldUserId = ''+ @UserId+'' GROUP BY DATENAME(DW, fldTimeStamp)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(L) AS 'Count', DATENAME(DW, fldTimeStamp) AS 'Day', @L AS 'Type' FROM [dbname].[FoodTypes]WHERE LEC = 1 AND fldUserId = ''+ @UserId+'' GROUP BY DATENAME(DW, fldTimeStamp)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(O) AS 'Count', DATENAME(DW, fldTimeStamp) AS 'Day', @F AS 'Type' FROM [dbname].[FoodTypes]WHERE OmegaFA = 1 AND fldUserId = ''+ @UserId+'' GROUP BY DATENAME(DW, fldTimeStamp)
```

In my C# code I am then creating four separate lists, which I am sure is wrong. Each list contains the correct data, so this part works. I have tried playing around with arrays and serializations, but I am stuck on how to take this further.

```
[Function(Name = "[dbname].[FoodCountCompare]")]
public List<FoodCountCompare> GetFoodCountCompare(){
        string UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var x = dc.FoodCountCompare(UserId).ToList();            

        var Protein = (from a in x where a.Type == "P" select new { a.Count, a.Day, a.Type }).ToList();
        var HEC = (from a in x where a.Type == "H" select new { a.Count, a.Day, a.Type }).ToList();
        var LEC = (from a in x where a.Type == "L" select new { a.Count, a.Day, a.Type }).ToList();
        var F = (from a in x where a.Type == "O" select new { a.Count, a.Day, a.Type }).ToList(); 

        //Add code to create JSON here
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string p = js.Serialize(Protein);
        string h = js.Serialize(HEC);
        string l = js.Serialize(LEC);
        string f = js.Serialize(F);

        return something_like_json;
    }

public JsonResult FoodCountCompare(){       
        var items = new List<FoodCountCompare>(GetFoodCountCompare());
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

For me the question is, how do you take this data and turn it into JSON, such a a nested array or straight set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
[Function(Name = "[dbname].[FoodCountCompare]")]
public List<FoodCountCompare> GetFoodCountCompare(){
    string UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var x = dc.FoodCountCompare(UserId).ToList();
    var items = x.Select(d => new FoodCountCompare { Type = d.Type, Day = d.Day, Count = d.Count }) 
    return items;
}

public JsonResult FoodCountCompare(){       
    var items = new List<FoodCountCompare>(GetFoodCountCompare());
    return Json(new {
        Protein = items.Where(d => d.Type == "P"),
        Hec = items.Where(d => d.Type == "H"),
        Lec = items.Where(d => d.Type == "L"),
        F = items.Where(d => d.Type == "O"),
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Which will result in 4 different arrays for each type:

```
{"Protein":[ ... ],"Hec":[ ... ], "Lec":[ ... ], "F":[ ... ]}
```

I believe you don't need to specify the exact json property names.

Comment: Yes, that is it...I will give it a go. I have been reading Newton all day and didn't see anything like this...

Comment: Its not really Newton, I am just creating C# anonymous type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

Comment: It works perfectly, I only made one adjustment. I will read the link you sent as well.  Marked as correct answer.